# What happens if a server never receives the RST packet?

Tags: tcp, ddos, rst

Someone recently decided to show me a POC of a new Denial of Service method using SYN/TCP he's figured out. I thought it was complete nonsense, but after explaining to him about SYN-SYN/ACK-RST, he left me speechless. He told me "what if the server you're using to trick into sending the SYN/ACK packets can't receive the RST packet?"

I have no idea. He claims that the server will continue trying to send SYN/ACK packets, and that the packetrate will continue to build up.

Is there any truth to this? Can anyone elaborate?

Apparently, the way it works is this:

He spoofs the IP of the SYN packet to the target's IP.
He then sends the SYN packet to a handful of random servers
They all reply with their SYN/ACK packet to the target IP, of course
The target responds with RST, as we know
**BUT** somehow he keeps the target from sending the RST or keeps the random servers from processing it
With this, apparently the servers will continue trying to send the SYN/ACK packets, thus producing a somewhat of a "snowball" effect.

Comment: Could you rough out what he thinks the packet-flow is for this attack? I'm having trouble visualizing it.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 Edited. Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you know, the "attempting to open a port" packet-flow is supposed to work like this:

1. SYN ->
2. <- SYN/ACK
3. ACK ->

The 'closed port' version is simple:

1. SYN ->
2. <- RST

And if the far end doesn't return RST packets, which is an extremely common firewall configuration:

1. SYN ->
2. [time passes]
3. SYN ->
4. [time passes]
5. SYN ->
6. [time passes]

And by extremely common I mean *extremely common*. All TCP stacks have to handle this case since it's so common.

The variant your someone proposed:

1. [Spoofed source] SYN ->
2. <- SYN/ACK
3. [time passes]
4. <- SYN/ACK
5. [time passes]
6. <- SYN/ACK

The 'attack' he's cleverly discovered is the [SYN Flood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_flood) attack, and has been known since the early 1990's. Thanks to firewalls blocking RST packets these servers won't know to close the connection, so they'll indeed retransmit the SYN/ACK packet based on the normal TCP retry timings. However, all modern TCP stacks do include some configurable measure of SYN-flood protection built into them.

This is still a somewhat effective method of attack, though the main harm it's caused is through overwhelming the perimeter security device with too many packets to keep track of. SYN/ACKs without a SYN should be dropped on the floor very cheaply, but if they come in enough numbers it can overwhelm a firewall.

Comment: Oh right. I suppose it *would* just be a standard SYN flood. And there goes my bewilderment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Syn Cookies](http://cr.yp.to/syncookies.html) effectively stop this attack. The server responds with a SYN/ACK, and forgets about it. If an ACK is received it then reinitialises the stream based on the TCP sequence number. On linux it's enabled by adding:

> net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1

to /etc/sysctl.conf

But when when being hammered by 10k+ machines, the server will still be taken down I reckon.